# Installable Trigger not triggered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-installable-triggers

I have installable trigger in my spreadsheet, however when i edit the sheet the trigger is not triggered

[image: the installable trigger screenshoot]

before is my trigger is fine, i already delete and add new trigger but still no triggered.

[image: project details screenshoot]

---

---Edited ---

this my configuration for each trigger

[image: newRow function trigger configuration]

[image: triggerpls function trigger configuration]

---

this the code i want to running

```
function triggerpls() {
  Utilities.sleep(2000);
  console.log("triggered");
}

function newRow(e) {
  
  var ROW_MODIFIED = ["INSERT_ROW"];
  if(ROW_MODIFIED.indexOf(e.changeType) == -1) return;
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var currentCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
 
  var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  
  
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, maxRows);
  
  
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var higher = Number(values.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[0]);
  currentCell.setValue(higher + 1);
  

}
```

Comment: Would you mind letting me know how you're assuming that your trigger is not getting triggered ?

Comment: Hello @Alcyone, do you get anything in your `Executions` tab? Also, what settings have you configured for the two triggers? Cheers!

Comment: @UmairMohammad i see theres no new executions.

Comment: @ale13 no iam not get anything from Executions tab, the configuration of two trigger is in edited question

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

The onChange() event only works on user edits.  It does not work when a script or a cell function makes an edit.

```
function newRow(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var sh=e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet2' && e.changeType=='INSERT_ROW') {
    var v=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().map(function(r,i){return r[0];}).filter(function(e){return e;});
    var h=Number(v.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[0]);
    sh.getCurrentCell().setValue(h+1);
  }
}
```